# Less "active" emacs string highlighting?

Tags: string, emacs, syntax-highlighting

The problem is when I type ' or " (in a number of modes including java, python, ruby, c) it somehow immediately wants to make-highlight the rest of the file after as a string. Would be so less annoying if it rather did nothing and *waited* for closing quote char. Could be ok for triple quotes in python but for ordinary?

Googling didn't help much since I'm having troubles with concise and distinctive formulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoPairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) in order to automatically add the second `"` when you type the first `"` (same thing for parentheses, braces, etc.).

The syntax highlighting will not be disturbed.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Though can "jumping" be switched off in autopair.el? It does that even 2 times. Since in case of brackets highlighting already shows correspondence.

Comment: Nevermind, found the variable `autopair-blink`. Guess you solved my problem and even more, appreciated a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Emacs does wait already.  So you may simply want to adjust the time it waits, which is controlled by `jit-lock-context-time`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know. Delayed highlight could still be helping and won't get in the way.